# How to navigate to a specific object location programatically in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When I have a bunch of objects on canvas at different locations and my web page has scrollbars for canvas area, I have navigation buttons for next/prev which makes the respective object as active by calling canvas.setActiveObject() but I need to auto scroll to that specific location.

I haven't found anything on the html canvas context to achieve that.

canvas.getContext().moveTo(x, y); moves the pointer logically but I need to move physically.

```js
function gonext(idx) {
  var objs = fcanvas.getObjects();
  fcanvas.setActiveObject(objs[idx]);
}

var fcanvas = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas");
fcanvas.setWidth(500);
fcanvas.setHeight(1200);
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#FF454F'  
});
fcanvas.add(rect);
fcanvas.setActiveObject(rect);
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 1100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#FF454F'
});
fcanvas.add(rect);
fcanvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
  <button onclick="gonext(1)">Next</button>
  <div >
      <canvas id="mycanvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle in action, clicking on NEXT will make the next object active but I also need to scroll down to that object

Any direction on this one?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle in action, clicking on NEXT will make the next object active but I also need to scroll down to that object

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hiitskiran/hamLh0f5/14/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to adjust offset in your page, but a simple `window.scrollTo` doens't help you?
Please try the executable snippet below:

```js
function gonext(idx) {
  var objs = fcanvas.getObjects();
  var obj = objs[idx];
  fcanvas.setActiveObject(obj);
  window.scrollTo(0, obj.top);
}

var fcanvas = new fabric.Canvas("mycanvas");
fcanvas.setWidth(500);
fcanvas.setHeight(1200);
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#FF454F'  
});
fcanvas.add(rect);
fcanvas.setActiveObject(rect);
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 1100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#FF454F'
});
fcanvas.add(rect);
fcanvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
  <button onclick="gonext(1)">Next</button>
  <div >
      <canvas id="mycanvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
  </div>
```

Comment: window.scrollTo() is the first thing I tried, the web page is like a widgets and each block has its on DIV with scrollbars.

Comment: right, I'd like to help you, but I need more context, I'm sorry

Comment: I even tried to set .scrollTop on the div enclosing canvas but didnt help

Comment: if you want, add the necessary markup to your question, so that I can reproduce better the  scenario, otherwise good luck, all the best

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was, canvas was inside a nested DIVs, I had do use.scrollTop on my root div to fix the issue